Show information based on phone number
We are a parcel delivery company looking to enhance a feature that uses a phone number to indicate a customer's success rate based on parcel returns. We have two UX versions in mind:

After validating the number, a simple card displays the overall summary.
After validating the number, the summary appears in tooltip and as a label below the input box.

Which UX approach would be better, and do you have any other UX ideas for this feature?


sorry, why do you have those messages in a Phone number field?

Unless you have some test results or have other findings that show problems with the current design, the question can only be answered with opinions. Can you edit the question so that it is more focused? Otherwise it might get closed.

Option 2 is a NO-GO. Because

The main information that the parcel delivery company needs to see is hidden inside a tooltip.
Tootltip is not the right UI element to use here. The usage of it can be studied here: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tooltip-guidelines/
Personally I don't like tooltips for main functions as its not really accessible across devices. And in some it might be click, on some its hover or tap.

Therefore I would suggest to go with Option 1.
There are ideas I can think about but I do not want to jump into solutions as the following information are not clear:

Is it part of a form?
Is identifying the success rate the primary JTBD? Else what is?
Are there other CTAs in the same page/form?

